# Variável não chama função, WebWorker e funções em Escopo

Tags: javascript

Estou com sérios problemas, tenho um WebWorker que importa um arquivo, mas na hora de chamar a função com a variável não funciona. Veja:

```js
importScripts(
  './libs/RSA.js'
);

self.onmessage = function (e) {
        JSEncrypt.getKey(function () {
          privateKey = RSA.getPrivateKey();
          publicKey = RSA.getPublicKey();
        });
}
```

O arquivo RSA nada mais é que: http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/bin/jsencrypt.js

O erro retornado é: **Uncaught TypeError: RSA.getKey is not a function**

Comment: Onde você definiu `RSA`, e qual o seu tipo? Não encontrei nenhuma variável chamada `RSA` no arquivo linkado...

Comment: Perdao o arquivo linkado tem variavel `JSEncrypt` e o meu foi alterado para `RSA`, mas arrumei pra questao. @mgibsonbr

Comment: Você usou esse `jsencrypt.js` tal como ele está, ou o adaptou de alguma forma? Testei aqui, e obtive `Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined` - o que é natural, uma vez que dentro do *web worker* não há acesso ao `window`. Ou seja, ele nem chegou a executar a linha onde define o `onmessage`, não respondendo a eventos enviados da página principal.

Comment: eu defini `var window = self;` @mgibsonbr de acordo com uma pergunta no SOen

Comment: Ok, vou repetir o teste. Por favor mencione esse tipo de coisa na pergunta, do contrário fica difícil saber o que está acontecendo. Sugiro também ler isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (P.S. Agora sim obtive o mesmo erro; já é um progresso... :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `getKey` não pertence a `JSEncrypt`, e sim a `JSEncrypt.prototype`. Isso significa que toda **instância** de `JSEncrypt` - criada via `new JSEncrypt(...)` - é quem terá esse método.

Crie uma instância do modo que achar melhor (com ou sem opções), e chame o método nela:

```
var window = self;
importScripts(
  'jsencrypt.js'
);

var meuRSA = new JSEncrypt();

self.onmessage = function (e) {
        meuRSA.getKey(function () {
          privateKey = meuRSA.getPrivateKey();
          publicKey = meuRSA.getPublicKey();

          // Para visualização
          console.log(privateKey);
          console.log('');
          console.log(publicKey);
        });
}
```

Comment: como eu pude errar isso ?? Meu Deus.. perco horas as vezes por coisas toa bobas que tenho vergonha..

Comment: Hehe se fosse assim tão bobo eu não teria demorado tanto pra achar o problema... :P Protótipos em JS são desnecessariamente confusos.

Comment: vc é agradável, mas acho que deveria existir algo que ajudasse a como revisar o codigo para encontrar o error.. tipo "padroes" mas acho que nao tem como..

Comment: @Elaine Historicamente tem sido muito difícil fazer esse tipo de análise em linguagens dinamicamente tipadas, tal como é feito naquelas com tipagem estática. O máximo que se consegue é alguma análise do script em si (ver [JSLint](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSLint)), mas sem aprofundar nas relações entre um arquivo e outro (e ainda sem checagem de tipos). Li há bastaaante tempo atrás que [algumas ferramentas para ajudar nisso estavam sendo desenvolvidas](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com.br/2008/05/dynamic-languages-strike-back.html), mas já se vão 7 anos e nunca mais ouvi falar disso... :(

Comment: Interessante a idéia proposta, mas acho que é algo muito complexo, e como nem todos programam igual com "padrões" definidos fica ainda mais difícil :/ QUem sabe até 2050 nao vemos algo voltado a esta area haha